# Cannot get validation messages to display PHP CSV import loop

Tags: php, validation

I'am trying to validate a CSV file that I import (see below exmaple). I cannot get the validation messages to display. Any suggestions to displaying the validation message? The insert doesn't work if the validation is not true, however I think this is the DB preventing it rather than the php. I assume it is to do with thelocation of the foreach that goes through the errors array, however the different places i place this seem not to help.

```
  $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
  $handle = fopen($file, "r");
  $errors = array();

if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
   do {
     if ($data[0]) {  
       if (!is_numeric($data[0])) {
       $errors[] = "#####My error msg#####";
       }

   if (!empty($errors)){
   foreach($errors as $error){
       echo $error;
       }
               }  else {
        $stmt = $conn ->prepare("INSERT INTO make_tbl (make) VALUES (?) returning make_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,($data[0]));
        $stmt->execute();           
        }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));

header('Location: importPDO.php');
}
```

Comment: Comment out `header('Location: importPDO.php');` and see if you see it then

Comment: Thanks, I have spent so long looking at this, I never would have thought to check that line. Which was obviously creating the page again after the msg is shown!